# Does taking derivative of determinant of a matrix with respect to an entry give a matrix or another determinant?

Tags: determinant, tensors

In page-139, Chapter-9 of Pavel Grinfeld's Tensor calculus, it is said said that for a given matrix $A$ having entries $a_i^j$ where $i$ is row and $j$ is column, the **Cofactor** is given by the following expression:

$$ \frac{\partial |A|}{\partial a_i^j}=A_j^i$$

Where $|A|$ is determinant of $A$. My question is whether $A_j^i$ is a matrix or a determinant? It looks to me that it should be a determinant:

$$A_r^i = \frac{\delta_{rst}^{ijk} }{2!}a_j^sa_k^t$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your formula $A_j^i$ is the **determinant** of the $(i,j)$ minor of $A$ multiplied by $(-1)^{i+j}$. It follows from the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)
along the row $i$:
$$\det(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{i+j}a_{i}^j\det(A_{ij}).$$

Comment: So, it is a cofactor and not a minor , right?

Comment: Yes a cofactor.